# Why's This Making an Infinite Loop?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer, infinite-loop

I am having a problem with gesture recognition in a subview of a UIView. My subview is a view that will be draggable through a UIPanGestureRecognizer - I know that part works. But I'm having a problem *getting the touches to that view in the first place*. The touches are coming to my UIView - not the subview I want them to go to. I've tried force-redirecting the touches to my target view with this code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"rT");
    [self.valueLabel touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"mT");
    [self.valueLabel touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"eT");
    [self.valueLabel touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

...but then my console goes crazy - infinite loop

```
...
2013-02-08 17:07:33.683 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.684 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.685 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.686 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.686 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.687 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.688 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.689 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.690 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.691 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.692 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.692 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.693 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.694 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.695 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.696 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.697 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.698 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.700 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.701 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.702 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.703 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.704 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.705 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.706 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.707 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.708 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.709 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.710 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.711 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
2013-02-08 17:07:33.713 Totalizer[3810:907] rT
...
```

I can't seem to figure this out.

Anything helps (within reason...)

Erway Software

Comment: because you're calling touchesBegan from within touchesBegan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted code goes into a loop because

`valueLabel` isn't responding to `touchesBegan:`, `touchesMoved:`, and `touchesEnded:`...
This calls trickle back up to your code.

It is an unintentional recursive loop.

Definitely drop that approach.  Have you tried `valueLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES`?

Answer (score 1):

Your touches are being forwarded to the superview of self.label which is self.  This is causing an infinite recursion.